# When is a container a monad?

Tags: ct.category-theory, computer-science, monads

[The category of polynomial functors on Set is equivalent to the category of containers.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/polynomial+functor)

[We have a prescription for when a container is a comonad.](https://lmcs.episciences.org/894/pdf)

There are a few other questions that come to mind.  The first question in my mind, though, was, given you have a polynomial functor on Set, what properties ensure it is a monad?

Comment: The title of the paper at the second link is catchy, but it seems a bit of a linguistic abuse to characterize its contents as describing when a container "is" a comonad. Since a single container can support multiple comonad structures (cf examples 3.2 and 3.3). Perhaps a clearer informal description of the contents would be "a characterization of a comonad whose underlying endofunctor is the interpretation of a container in terms of a structure that 'feels' more natural in the context of containers"

Comment: If you agree with this characterization, then perhaps your question could be reframed as something like "what is a characterization of a monad whose underlying endofunctor is a polynomial functor on Set in terms of a structure that 'feels' more natural in the context of polynomial functors?"